# `combine_first` at DST changing day fails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to use `combine_first` to join two pandas series, so that one has precedence over the other. But it fails on the DST change day. I put together this demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fr1 = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2020-10-25').tz_localize('Europe/Berlin'), pd.to_datetime('2020-10-26').tz_localize('Europe/Berlin'), freq='H')
fr2 = fr1 + pd.DateOffset(hours=12)
d1 = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(0,10, len(fr1)), index = fr1)
d2 = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(0,10, len(fr2)), index = fr2)
d2.combine_first(d1)
```

output:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Why is this? How can this be fixed? I can of course manually slice the series and concatenate.

Comment: btw. you can simplify to `pd.date_range('2020-10-25', '2020-10-26', tz='Europe/Berlin', freq='H')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see looking at the first items of your `DateTimeIndex`, the timezone as `+xxxx` changes at the moment of DST change:

```
>>> date_range = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2020-10-25').tz_localize('Europe/Berlin'), pd.to_datetime('2020-10-26').tz_localize('Europe/Berlin'), freq='H')
>>> date_range[:4]
DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-25 00:00:00+02:00', '2020-10-25 01:00:00+02:00',
               '2020-10-25 02:00:00+02:00', '2020-10-25 02:00:00+01:00'],
```

When you add the 12 hours, the dates change their timezones too:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-25 12:00:00+01:00', '2020-10-25 13:00:00+01:00',
               '2020-10-25 14:00:00+01:00', '2020-10-25 14:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]', freq=None)
```

However the difference in time is not 12 hours anymore, it is 11 due to the timezone change. That is because when adding `DateOffset` to a `DatetimeIndex`, you ask for a « apparent » change of 12 hours, as in « the 2 different clock readings are 12 hours apart ». This means that then 2 timestamps are mapped to the same timestamp that appears 12 hours later.

It is a specificity of `DateOffset` to allow to express non-constant deltas, i.e. if you add « 1 month », you would similarly not add the same number of seconds to a date depending which month you’re in.

If you want a shift in 12 actual hours, use `Timedelta`:

```
>>> (date_range[:4] + pd.Timedelta(hours=12))
DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-25 11:00:00+01:00', '2020-10-25 12:00:00+01:00',
               '2020-10-25 13:00:00+01:00', '2020-10-25 14:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]', freq='H')
>>> (date_range + pd.Timedelta(hours=12)).is_unique
True
```

Now that the index is unique, `combine_first` will also work:

```
>>> d1 = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, 26), index=date_range)
>>> d2 = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, 26), index=date_range + pd.Timedelta(hours=12))
>>> d2.combine_first(d1)
2020-10-25 00:00:00+02:00    0.0
2020-10-25 01:00:00+02:00    1.0
2020-10-25 02:00:00+02:00    2.0
2020-10-25 02:00:00+01:00    1.0
2020-10-25 03:00:00+01:00    7.0
2020-10-25 04:00:00+01:00    4.0
2020-10-25 05:00:00+01:00    0.0
2020-10-25 06:00:00+01:00    1.0
2020-10-25 07:00:00+01:00    1.0
2020-10-25 08:00:00+01:00    1.0
2020-10-25 09:00:00+01:00    6.0
2020-10-25 10:00:00+01:00    7.0
2020-10-25 11:00:00+01:00    4.0
2020-10-25 12:00:00+01:00    8.0
2020-10-25 13:00:00+01:00    6.0
2020-10-25 14:00:00+01:00    0.0
2020-10-25 15:00:00+01:00    6.0
2020-10-25 16:00:00+01:00    0.0
2020-10-25 17:00:00+01:00    0.0
2020-10-25 18:00:00+01:00    9.0
2020-10-25 19:00:00+01:00    7.0
2020-10-25 20:00:00+01:00    9.0
2020-10-25 21:00:00+01:00    3.0
2020-10-25 22:00:00+01:00    4.0
2020-10-25 23:00:00+01:00    0.0
2020-10-26 00:00:00+01:00    6.0
2020-10-26 01:00:00+01:00    5.0
2020-10-26 02:00:00+01:00    9.0
2020-10-26 03:00:00+01:00    1.0
2020-10-26 04:00:00+01:00    4.0
2020-10-26 05:00:00+01:00    4.0
2020-10-26 06:00:00+01:00    3.0
2020-10-26 07:00:00+01:00    1.0
2020-10-26 08:00:00+01:00    8.0
2020-10-26 09:00:00+01:00    1.0
2020-10-26 10:00:00+01:00    6.0
2020-10-26 11:00:00+01:00    5.0
2020-10-26 12:00:00+01:00    6.0
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('2020-10-25').tz_localize('Europe/Berlin') + pd.DateOffset(hours=3)` returns `Timestamp('2020-10-25 02:00:00+0100', tz='Europe/Berlin')`. Doesn't this mean the `pd.DateOffset` is actual real physical time, not the wall time offset?

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 It seems to only happen on `DatetimeIndex`es indeed. `pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.to_datetime('2020-10-25').tz_localize('Europe/Berlin')]) + pd.DateOffset(hours=3)` returns `2020-10-25 03:00:00+01:00`

Comment: from the documentation: "However, all DateOffset subclasses that are an hour or smaller (Hour, Minute, Second, Milli, Micro, Nano) behave like Timedelta and respect absolute time." 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Comment: Maybe a bug then? Not sure.

Comment: This inconsistency between datetimeindex and just timestamp is a bad bug I think.

Comment: btw. pd.DateOffset(hours=12) behaves like pd.Timedelta(hours=12) if you do the addition in UTC: `fr2 = (fr1.tz_convert('UTC') + pd.DateOffset(hours=12)).tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')`